# Ng2-smart-table call 'Add New' link functionality from some other button/action reside outside the table

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

Ng2-smart-table call 'Add New' link functionality from some other button/action reside outside the table.

We want to hide the existing 'Add New' link and call the same functionality from some other action of my page.

The Mode = 'inline'.

The search filter and 'add new' are a bit confusing for the end user.